# Problem with installation of Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04

I am new at Linux operating systems. I have installed the latest version of Ubuntu 10.10 desktop edition on my laptop while still in Windows. I then rebooted and chose Ubuntu. It starts to load and it loads a little while and the screen goes blank. Like it stops loading in the system and nothing happens. I do not need it for games or such. Just to listen to music and for presentations and such things. Could it do something with my laptop? Its a Gericom laptop Intel Celeron processor 1300 Mhz 480MB of RAM.

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking. Please rephrase as a simple question. Include as much *relevant* information as possible - especially which version you have installed and how you installed it.

Comment: Try 10.04, as 10.10 is still beta and there are bugs!

Comment: @user2365: Note that Ubuntu 10.10 is in beta. If you want a system that works now, get Ubuntu 10.04. Trying 10.10 is good for the community though: you can help 10.10 be better when it's released. A blank screen is often a problem with the driver for the video chip. What is the exact model of your laptop (you've only given the brand and processor specs), and what video chip does it have?

Comment: I'm not sure if @user2365 *is* using 10.10. It says 10.10 in the question but is tagged with 10.04. The only way for us to know which one it s is for @user2365 to clarify.

Comment: This web site, http://www.linux-on-laptops.com/gericom.html, has experiences of others installing Linux on gericom laptops. You may get lucky and find your laptop model and hints about how to get it to work. Trying a live CD with various startup options is always a good idea with laptops, although 480mb of ram may be a little light for Ubuntu.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this question incomprehensible? Everyone else seems to be voting it up.

Comment: @lionm2 This question is far too vague for anyone to provide a clear and concise answer. Please edit your question with more details or an exact issue. I understand this can be a difficult issue to troubleshoot - especially as a new Linux user. Unfortunately this site doesn't work like a message forum or chat room - as outlined in our [FAQ](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/faq) If you can't narrow the question's scope you may need to seek out more [official support](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a stable Ubuntu release. Currently it is Ubuntu Lucid (10.04).

And since your laptop only has a limited amount of RAM, perhaps you want to try an Ubuntu Remix, which is targeted at such machines (e.g. Xubuntu or Lubuntu).